# Explain the working of ng-model and ng-show directives behind the scenes

Tags: angularjs

The following code displays/hides the content based on whether the check box is checked or not. Pl. tell me in detail how ng-model and ng-show directives are working together behind the scenes to produce the desired result.

```
<input ng-model="toggleDisplayHide" type="checkbox"/>
<div ng-show="toggleDisplayHide">Some text goes here ...</div>
```

The ng-show directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression specified in the ng-show attribute. Is toggleDisplayHide an expression?

The ng-model directive binds the value of HTML controls to app data. Is toggleDisplayHide referring to app data here?

Is this something like this:
When the checkbox is checked, the ng-model sets the value of toggleDisplayHide to true. And ng-show comes to know that the value of the expression toggleDisplayHide is set to true, it displays the content.

Comment: Ideally you should be reading angularjs docs / tutorials to get your answer..
Anyways, at a high level, ng-model specifies the model property / field that's tied with the input element. The value of toggleDisplayHide would toggle when the checkbox is checked / unchekced and it's this value that decides whether the text after is hidden or shown.

Answer (score 0):

Angular docs is a great place to know about those things and It's well documented as well. Just added some excerpt from the docs here:

> ng-show

The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag).

**[Refer DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)**

> ng-model

The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

ngModel is responsible for:

- Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as
  input, textarea or select require.
- Providing validation behavior (i.e. required, number, email, url).
  Keeping the state of the control (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine,
  touched/untouched, validation errors).
- Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid,
  ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched) including
  animations.
- Registering the control with its parent form.

> Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the
>   expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist
>   on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

[Refer DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

> **Based on that, Now to your question:**

`ng-show` will evaluate the expression `toggleDisplayHide` in scope and if its truthy will display the DOM else will hide.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model gives real taste of two way binding of the angularjs. The attribute provided to ngModel will bind to the respective scope property. If the property does not exist in the scope, angularjs will create automatically. So attribute should be  a scope property at the end

ng-show simply hide/show some html content depending on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The expression can be any valid javascript expression. If the expression is Truthy, html content will be shown, otherwise it will be hidden. ngShow simply uses css property display:hide/show